# css3 animation - trouble understanding css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

There is a delay in my CSS animation.
I would like the animation start without delay. Tried to change some values below but couldn't archieve the result.

```
.wpb_start_animation.wpb_appear {
animation: 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) 0s normal none 1 running wpb_appear;
}
```

Page: [www.globalig.com](http://www.globalig.com)

Thanks.

Comment: The page is still "loading" therefore animation is delayed.

Comment: No delay here. Try Chrome Dev Tools, locate ".wpb_start_animation.wpb_appear" and try checking/unchecking "the "webkit-animation" property. No delay. The cause is something else.

Comment: I actually was inspecting in GCH dev tools and I got 300ms page load (just to "download" page) I am in Europe. (and have good internet connection). See here http://i.stack.imgur.com/PqQdk.png

Answer (score 2):

The animation is only being started by the jQuery. Therefore, until the jQuery has loaded, you won't see anything.

Try adding the `.wpb_start_animation` directly to your containers, instead of the `.wpb_animate_when_almost_visible` class.